# Why does method backtrack not work when called from within method

Tags: java, backtracking

When I call method backtrack a second time from within it (backtrack) because I need to go back two moves, it does not work.  Does anyone have any idea?  Here is my code:

```
// width of board
static final int SQUARES = 8;

// board
static boolean[][] board = new boolean[SQUARES][SQUARES];

// represents values for number of squares eliminated if queen is placed in square
static int[][] elimination = new int[SQUARES][SQUARES];

// store position of queens
static boolean[][] position = new boolean[SQUARES][SQUARES];

// store row
static int[] row = new int[8];

// store column
static int[] column = new int[8];

// Write a program to solve the Eight Queens problem
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Arrays.fill(row, -1);
    Arrays.fill(column, -1);

    // reset elimination table
    fillElim();

    // count queens on board
    short counter = 0;

    // while board is not full
    while(counter < 8) {
        // place next queen on board
        placeQueen(-1, -1);

        // reset elimination table
        fillElim();

        // backtrack and fill board back to this point
        while(isFull() && counter < 7)
            backtrack(counter);

        counter++;

    }   // end while

    System.out.println("Queens on board: " + counter);
    printBoard();

    for(int i = 0; i < row.length; i++)
        System.out.println(column[i] + "/" + row[i]);

}   // end method main

// Print elimination table
public static void printE()
{
    for(int i[] : elimination) {
        for(int j = 0; j < i.length; j++)
            System.out.printf("%-3d", i[j]);

        System.out.println();

    }   // end for
}   // end printE

public static void printBoard()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {

            if(board[i][j] && position[i][j])
                System.out.print("o ");
            else if(board[i][j])
                System.out.print("x ");
            else
                System.out.print("% ");

        }   // end inner for

        System.out.println();

    }   // end outer for
}   // end method printBoard

// Write method to calculate how many squares are eliminated if queen is placed in that square
public static void fillElim()
{
    // if any squares that could be eliminated already are eliminated, subtract 1
    for(int i = 0; i < elimination.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < elimination[i].length; j++) {

            elimination[i][j] = openSquares(i, j);

        }   // end inner for
    }   // end outer for
}   // end method fillElimination

// Number of squares eliminatable by placing queen in any given square
public static int openSquares(int row, int column)
{
    // if square is already eliminated, it cannot be used
    if(board[row][column])
        return 0;

    // total number of squares elimintable from any given square, count square itself
    int total = 1 + openHorizontal(row) + openVertical(column) + openUpSlope(row, column) + openDownSlope(row, column);

    return total;
}   // end method openSquares

// Return number of open squares in a row
public static int openHorizontal(int row)
{
    // total of row
    int total = 0;

    for(boolean b : board[row]) {

        // if square is "true" (open), increment total open squares
        if(!b)
            total++;

    }   // end for

    // return total not counting current square
    return total - 1;

}   // end method openHorizontal

// Return number of open squares in a column
public static int openVertical(int column)
{
    // total of column
    int total = 0;

    // if square is "true" (open), increment total open squares
    for(boolean[] b : board) {

        // if square is "true" (open), increment total open square
        if(!b[column])
            total++;

    }   // end for

    // return total not counting current square
    return total - 1;

}   // end method openVertical

// Return number of open squares in a column
public static int openDownSlope(int x, int y)
{
    // total of downward-sloping diagonal
    int total = 0;

    // if square is "true" (open), increment total open squares
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {

        // test all values before use to prevent array index errors
        // all squares to the top right of the checking square
        if(x+i >= 0 && x+i < board.length && y+i >= 0 && y+i < board.length) {

            // else increment total
            if(!board[x+i][y+i])
                total++;

        }   // end if

        // all squares to the bottom left of the checking square
        if(x-i >= 0 && x-i < board.length && y-i >= 0 && y-i < board.length) {

            // else increment total
            if(!board[x-i][y-i])
                total++;

        }   // end if
    }   // end for

    // return total not counting current square
    return total - 2;

}   // end method openDownSlope

// Return number of open squares in a column
public static int openUpSlope(int x, int y)
{
    // total of upward-sloping diagonal
    int total = 0;

    // if square is "true" (open), increment total open squares
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {

        // test all values before use to prevent array index errors
        // all squares to the top right of the checking square
        if(x+i >= 0 && x+i < board.length && y-i >= 0 && y-i < board.length) {

            // else increment total
            if(!board[x+i][y-i])
                total++;

        }   // end if

        // all squares to the bottom left of the checking square
        if(x-i >= 0 && x-i < board.length && y+i >= 0 && y+i < board.length) {

            // else increment total
            if(!board[x-i][y+i])
                total++;

        }   // end if
    }   // end for

    // return total not counting current square
    return total - 2;

}   // end method openDownSlope

// Are all squares on the board filled?
public static boolean isFull()
{
    for(boolean b[] : board) {
        for(boolean bb : b) {

            if(!bb)
                return false;

        }   // end inner for
    }   // end outer for

    // if this point is reached, board is full
    return true;

}   // end method isFull

// Place a queen on the board
public static void placeQueen(int lastRow, int lastCol)
{
    int[] bestSquare = bestMove(lastRow, lastCol);

    System.out.println("&&&&&&");

    for(int i = 0; i < row.length; i++)
        System.out.println(row[i] + "/" + column[i]);

    System.out.println("&&&&&&");

    // assign queen to board
    board[bestSquare[0]][bestSquare[1]] = true;

    printBoard();
    System.out.println();

    // clear blocked squares from board
    elimSquares(bestSquare[0], bestSquare[1]);

    // reset elimination table
    fillElim();

    // store squares
    for(int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {

        if(row[i] == -1) {
            row[i] = bestSquare[0];
            column[i] = bestSquare[1];
            break;

        }   // end if
    }   // end for

    // mark queen's position
    position[bestSquare[0]][bestSquare[1]] = true;

    printBoard();

}   // end method placeQueen

// Return lowest number in elimination table
public static int[] bestMove(int lastRow, int lastCol)
{
    // store lowest number - set to impossibly low
    int low = 100;

    // store coordinates
    int[] move = {-1, -1};

    // store limit of use
    int limit;

    if(lastRow == -1)
        limit = 0;
    else
        limit = elimination[lastRow][lastCol];

    // if lastRow is not -1, search for duplicate numbers after current square
    if(lastRow != -1) {

        // test for equal elimination numbers farther down on board
        for(int i = lastRow; i < board.length; i++) {
            for(int j = lastCol+1; j < board[i].length; j++) {

                if(!board[i][j] && elimination[i][j] == limit) {
                    move[0] = i;
                    move[1] = j;
                    return move;
                }

            }   // end inner for
        }   // end outer for
    }   // end if

    // test for any available squares left on board
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {

            if(!board[i][j] && elimination[i][j] > limit && elimination[i][j] < low)
                low = elimination[i][j];

        }   // end inner for
    }   // end outer for

    // get move coordinates for square, if needed to get best square after two backtracks
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {

            if(!board[i][j] && elimination[i][j] == low) {

                move[0] = i;
                move[1] = j;
                return move;

            }   // end if
        }   // end inner for
    }   // end outer for

    return move;

}   // end method bestMove

public static void elimSquares(int row, int column)
{
    // total number of squares elimintable from any given square, count square itself
    elimHorizontal(row);
    elimVertical(column);
    elimUpSlope(row, column);
    elimDownSlope(row, column);

}   // end method openSquares

// Eliminate row
public static void elimHorizontal(int row)
{
    // eliminate row
    for (int i = 0; i < board[row].length; i++)
        board[row][i] = true;

}   // end method elimHorizontal

// Eliminate column
public static void elimVertical(int column)
{
    // eliminate column
    for(boolean[] b : board)
        b[column] = true;

}   // end method elimVertical

// Eliminate downward slope
public static void elimDownSlope(int x, int y)
{
    // loop through downward slope
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {

        // test all values before use to prevent array index errors

        // eliminate all squares to the bottom right of the checking square
        if(x+i >= 0 && x+i < board.length && y+i >= 0 && y+i < board.length)
            board[x+i][y+i] = true;

        // eliminate all squares to the top left of the checking square
        if(x-i >= 0 && x-i < board.length && y-i >= 0 && y-i < board.length)
            board[x-i][y-i] = true;

    }   // end for
}   // end method elimDownSlope

// Eliminate upward slope
public static void elimUpSlope(int x, int y)
{
    // loop through upward slope
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {

        // test all values before use to prevent array index errors

        // eliminate all squares to the bottom right of the checking square
        if(x+i >= 0 && x+i < board.length && y-i >= 0 && y-i < board.length)
            board[x+i][y-i] = true;

        // eliminate all squares to the top left of the checking square
        if(x-i >= 0 && x-i < board.length && y+i >= 0 && y+i < board.length)
            board[x-i][y+i] = true;

    }   // end for
}   // end method elimDownSlope

// If not found solution and board is full
public static void backtrack(int lastMove)
{
    // store last move
    int lastRow = row[lastMove];
    int lastCol = column[lastMove];

    // clear board
    resetBoard();

    // go back 1 move
    goBack(lastMove);

    // refill board
    for(int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {

        // escape if out of bounds
        if(row[i] == -1)
            break;

        // replace queens
        board[row[i]][column[i]] = true;

        // fill elimination table
        elimSquares(row[i], column[i]);

    }   // end for

    // while no open squares, go back one more row
    // keep track of times looped
    int counter = 0;

    while(!openSpaces(lastRow, lastCol)) {
        System.out.println("backtrack " + counter);
        backtrack(lastMove-1);
        counter++;
    }   // end while

    // set queen in square
    placeQueen(lastRow, lastCol);

}   // end method backtrack

// Clear board
public static void resetBoard()
{
    // clear board
    for(boolean[] b : board)
        for(int j = 0; j < b.length; j++)
            b[j] = false;

}   // end method resetBoard

// Go back 1 move
public static void goBack(int lastMove)
{
    // remove queen from last position
    position[row[lastMove]][column[lastMove]] = false;

    // remove last move from table
    row[lastMove] = -1;
    column[lastMove] = -1;

}   // end method goBack

// Return number of open, untested spaces on board
public static boolean openSpaces(int lastRow, int lastCol)
{
    // store number of open, untested squares
    int squares = 0;

    // store limit of use
    int limit = elimination[lastRow][lastCol];

    // store next limit for use if no more squares at limit
    int nextLimit = limit + 1;

    // test for equal elimination numbers farther down on board
    for(int i = lastRow; i < board.length; i++) {
        for(int j = lastCol+1; j < board[i].length; j++) {

            if(!board[i][j] && elimination[i][j] == limit)
                squares++;

        }   // end inner for
    }   // end outer for

    // test for any available squares left on board
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {

            if(!board[i][j] && elimination[i][j] >= nextLimit)
                squares++;

        }   // end inner for
    }   // end outer for

    return squares != 0;

}   // end method openSpaces
```

This calls method goBack; method placeQueen, which calls method bestMove; and a few others.  These three mentioned methods may also have an error, I do not know for sure:

```
// Go back 1 move
public static void goBack(int lastMove)
{
    // remove queen from last position
    position[row[lastMove]][column[lastMove]] = false;

    // remove last move from table
    row[lastMove] = -1;
    column[lastMove] = -1;

}   // end method goBack

// Place a queen on the board
public static void placeQueen(int lastRow, int lastCol)
{
    int[] bestSquare = bestMove(lastRow, lastCol);

    System.out.println("&&&&&&");

    for(int i = 0; i < row.length; i++)
        System.out.println(row[i] + "/" + column[i]);

    System.out.println("&&&&&&");

    // assign queen to board
    board[bestSquare[0]][bestSquare[1]] = true;

    printBoard();
    System.out.println();

    // clear blocked squares from board
    elimSquares(bestSquare[0], bestSquare[1]);

    // reset elimination table
    fillElim();

    // store squares
    for(int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {

        if(row[i] == -1) {
            row[i] = bestSquare[0];
            column[i] = bestSquare[1];
            break;

        }   // end if
    }   // end for

    // mark queen's position
    position[bestSquare[0]][bestSquare[1]] = true;

    printBoard();

}   // end method placeQueen

// Return lowest number in elimination table
public static int[] bestMove(int lastRow, int lastCol)
{
    // store lowest number - set to impossibly low
    int low = 100;

    // store coordinates
    int[] move = {-1, -1};

    // store limit of use
    int limit;

    if(lastRow == -1)
        limit = 0;
    else
        limit = elimination[lastRow][lastCol];

    // if lastRow is not -1, search for duplicate numbers after current square
    if(lastRow != -1) {

        // test for equal elimination numbers farther down on board
        for(int i = lastRow; i < board.length; i++) {
            for(int j = lastCol+1; j < board[i].length; j++) {

                if(!board[i][j] && elimination[i][j] == limit) {
                    move[0] = i;
                    move[1] = j;
                    return move;
                }

            }   // end inner for
        }   // end outer for
    }   // end if

    // test for any available squares left on board
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {

            if(!board[i][j] && elimination[i][j] > limit && elimination[i][j] < low)
                low = elimination[i][j];

        }   // end inner for
    }   // end outer for

    // get move coordinates for square, if needed to get best square after two backtracks
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {

            if(!board[i][j] && elimination[i][j] == low) {

                move[0] = i;
                move[1] = j;
                return move;

            }   // end if
        }   // end inner for
    }   // end outer for

    return move;

}   // end method bestMove
```

I think that placeQueen is somehow being called before backtrack within the backtrack method.

P.S.  This is not the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111154/use-elimination-heuristic-to-solve-eight-queens-puzzle.  There I was asking what I needed to do; here I am asking why my method did not work.

Comment: Is it possible you could trim down the code to the minimum that demonstrates your problem? Or at least explicitly show what piece of code is failing? That's a lot of code to sort through trying to find your problem.

Comment: I think you need to write: if(!openSpaces(lastRow, lastCol)) { ... } else { placeQueen(lastRow, lastCol); }

Comment: @jpmc26  Sure.  I thought you might like to run it, and I do have some output to show what is happening wrong, but I will separate the piece that I think is failing, at least where I know the fail starts.

Comment: @SpiderPig  Actually, I want while(!openSpaces(lastRow, lastCol)){...} because I want to continue going up an entry if it returns dead (no next move available).  Then, I want it to replace the removed queen by entering a queen in the next best spot open.  I will try your suggestion and see how it works.

Comment: Actually, you cannot use if-else because you do not know whether you merely replaced the value and should leave main's counter alone, or whether you jumped back.  You must always use while, and replace your queen.  After second thoughts, I am sure that the trouble is in bestMove because the second backtrack is called and returns the same value, and because in other places it just flops back and forth between two values for a queen.  Neither of these should happen, and bestMove is what takes care of this.

Comment: I haven't really been able to go through your code yet, but I can offer one piece of advice that's done wonders for my own code: write extremely short methods. Each method should have only one or two things (maybe 3, in a few cases) for you to understand about the method itself, and any other required logic is pushed off into other methods it calls. Also give it a name that tells you what it does. In other words, make each method dead simple and understandable with only a few glances. That will force you to think through all your logic thoroughly and make it easier to find the problem.

Comment: Thank you.  I do try to do that, but sometimes it is hard, especially when it is the method that returns the final product to the caller, where you may need to call many methods to get the final product.  If you look, I have 1 method each for calculating the free spaces in the rows, columns, and diagonals, and 1 for returning the sums (plus the square itself); 1 each for marking the squares in the rows, columns, and diagonals as dead; etc.

Comment: If the function openSpaces(lastRow, lastColumn) gives you true if there are squares available for the move then your while loop in function backtrack is negating it by adding a ! in condition. This is what I perceive.

Comment: @jsjunkie  That is what I intend.  That is to make sure that there is a square that I can enter my next queen in after running through backtrack until I am back to my original point.

Comment: That's right, so say you have squares value greater than zero, your openSpaces function will return true in that case. Lets say now openSpaces = true, then in the while loop you have written while (!openSpaces), this will become while(false) and hence process won't enter in while loop.

Comment: @jsjunkie  Yes. Then I just need to replace the last value, not backtrack once more, then replace two values to be at starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is btw. a simpler way to solve the queens problem.
This program will print out all 92 solutions.

```
public class Queens {
    static int counter = 0;
    static int[] pos = new int[8];

    static void printBoard(){
        for(int p: pos) {
            for(int i = 0; i < p; i++) System.out.print(".");
            System.out.print("Q");
            for(int i = p+1; i < 8; i++) System.out.print(".");
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    static boolean threatened(int x, int y){
        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++){
            int d = y - i;
            if(pos[i] == x || pos[i] == x - d || pos[i] == x + d) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    static void place(int y) {
        for(int x = 0; x < pos.length ; x++){
            if(!threatened(x, y)){
                pos[y] = x;
                if(y == 7){
                    printBoard();
                    counter++;
                } else{
                    place(y + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        place(0);
        System.out.print("found " + counter + " solutions");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice job.  My textbook suggested using an elimination heuristic, so that is what I started with.

Comment: Actually, you should really post that answer on my other question, which dealt with this.  Here I was asking why my code wasn't working, not how to do it.